# Deploy and execute something with Java on UNIX

Tags: java, unix, zip, setup-deployment

I have a Java process (daemon) which is running. This process is used like a service. With that service I can download a signed zip archive from a trusted server. After I unpack the ZIP archive I want to execute a binary in the "unpacked" folder.

The problem is that this binary is not executable (no 'x' in its file mode) ... I know it's possible to set it with Java but I want a generic way.

Do you have any ideas how to do the deployment in a nice way?

(Yes, it needs to be Java)

Basically I want to restore the Unix file mode bits after I unpacked the ZIP archive. Is there a Java Lib which can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a nice way? If you have control over files going into the archive then just make sure the binary has the proper modes before packing it up.

Comment: @Perception: Not all zip compressors support storing the Unix file mode bits. And not all zip decompressors support restoring it...

Comment: @thkala That's what I need. Is there a Java Lib which can do this?

Comment: @alexvetter: I am not aware of any Java Zip library that supports Unix permissions. There is at least one related SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1050560/507519).

Comment: Hmm, apparently [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net/truezip-driver/truezip-driver-zip/index.html) has some initial support for extended file attributes, but it does not seem complete to the point of being usable for Unix permissions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily [call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) the [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) command from your Java application to add that missing `x` bit. `chmod` is as standard on Unix as the executable (`x`) bit itself.

Or you could do it [straight from Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable%28boolean,%20boolean%29).

If you want the executable bit to remain set at decompression, though, you should probably not use the Java decompression libraries. Try using the Unix [`unzip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) command to decompress your archive - it has supported storing and restoring the Unix file mode bits for quite some time. If your Unix vendor does not have it, you can get it from [the source](http://www.info-zip.org/).

Comment: Sorry, you're not helping. I can set the executeable flag right from Java. I don't know about all binaries so I can't set the flag. Nicest thing would be to "unpack" the archive and the flags are already set.

Comment: 'unzip -X' keeps the GID/UID. Problem is that jarsigner (tool which I use for signing) doesn't preserve the flags. So it will not work with out of the box. I'm think about adding a metainfofile which contains all executable files. 'find . -executable -type f' can help with that.

Comment: @alexvetter: so by the time your application receives the archive, the executable bits have already been lost :-/

Comment: Apache Commons Compress' ZipArchiveEntry has the method getExternalAttributes(). With it you can get the flags (777) (you have to convert the long into octal representation). But anyway as I said this won't work for me (jarsigner problem).If it comes to a normal zip file your answer would be the best.

Comment: I'm going to implement another way of ensure that zip files were not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you pack your files with `tar` and then optionally compress, it keeps your permissions as they were before packing. Use `--preserve-permissions` when unpacking.