# Can i store unix permissions in a zip file (built with apache ant)?

Tags: java, linux, zip

I'm building a linux installer for a Java application, and I end up with an install.jar and a setup.sh that I put in a zip file using ant.

The idea is the user unzips the zip file and then runs setup.sh but the trouble is that they always need to chmod setup.sh first to give themselves execute permissions.

I want to remove this step and Im not sure if the problem part is:

1. That Im building on Windows
2. That Im building with ant zip task
3. Or that zips cannot presreve permissions and will always unzip without x permissions.

Comment: Permissions are external to the file, and particular to the filesystem. So, even if I cannot give an argumented answer, I vote for 3). Also, which permissions do you want to pass from your Windows FS to Unix? Even if zip supports that, building the file from windows makes no sense.

Comment: Windows doesn't have the same perms as Unix; IIRC it'll default to `0666` for files. Or `0644`?. Which is less-funny than 666. I don't know if you can override it or not.

Comment: I just want execute permission for the user, I could create the zip on linux if I really have to but would that fix it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>You cannot store Linux/Unix file permissions in a ZIP file.</strike>

**Edit (after comments)** by using the "external attributes" field inside the ZIP header these attributes can be store inside a ZIP file. GNU's `unzip` is apparently able to read that additional field and restore file permissions. <sup>I'm not sure when this was added to the ZIP format as the early versions - coming from a MS-DOS world - did not have support for this.</sup>

The TAR format - being a "native" Unix/Linux format - has been designed to include file attributes and Ant can create TAR files that will preserve attributes across all Linux/Unix operating systems.

```
<tar compression="gzip" destfile="my-archive.tgz">
  <tarfileset mode="544" dir="dir_with_shell_scripts">
     <include name="*.sh"/>
  </tarfileset>
</tar>
```

Comment: Thankyou that worked :) , my only concern is that when a user downloads this file they need to do 'tar xvf file' which is rather less intuitive than 'unzip file'

Comment: @PaulTaylor: for Unix/Linux users the tar format is (usually) much more natural than the ZIP format.

Comment: It is in fact possible to smuggle Unix permissions into a ZIP file, in the "Extra" field.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip/434689#434689

Comment: @offby1: interesting. Do the usual unzip programs honour this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the "unzip" on RHEL 5.3 does, I know that much :)

Comment: See @Blaine's answer for a real solution

Comment: @Liosan: it might be the better answer, but I don't see a reason to downvote my (working) answer because of that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The reason for the downvote is because you state "You cannot store Linux/Unix file permissions in a ZIP file.", which is not true :)

Comment: @Liosan: I edited my answer. But it's still unclear to me if those external attributes work for all Unix/Linux flavors? (Solaris, AIX, MacOS, BSD, ...). The `tar` format *does*.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, downvote reverted :) Indeed those attributes in .zipfiles are a bit fishy.

Comment: Unix `unzip` restores permissions by default, and `[sudo] unzip -X [-K]` also restores UID and GID.

Answer (score 27):

You don't have to switch to tar files.  I don't know why people who don't know Ant are offering advice on this topic.

Use zipfileset's filemode parameter.  Documented at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html

Comment: A concrete example wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Blaine’s answer, you can use [<zipfileset>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) child elements to specify permissions:

```xml
<zip destfile="build/MyApplication.zip" encoding="UTF-8">

    <zipfileset dir="${content-dir}" encoding="UTF-8"
        includes="**/setup.sh" filemode="755"/>

    <zipfileset dir="${content-dir}" encoding="UTF-8"
        excludes="**/setup.sh"/>

</zip>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html).

First paragraph:

> Access to internal and external attributes (which are used to store Unix permission by some zip implementations).

Take a look at the [API](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveEntry.html) and look for `setUnixMode()`

Comment: Interesting, found an ant lib for this as well http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/compress/

Answer (score 1):

zip/unzip in modern linux distros will preserve file permissions.
But you need to make sure that the zip in windows honours this.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a tar file instead of a zip file, it should preserve the permissions for you.  The files' owners and groups might not match up, but the permission bits will.

Answer (score -1):

```
<shellscript shell="sh" dir="abc" failonerror="true">
            zip -ry abc.zip *
</shellscript>
```

The ant script above invokes a shell script to create the zip archive in which the permissions are very well preserved. It works with Ant 1.7 and above. However I have not tried verified running this ant script on windows. This works very well on mac.